# How to detect "Cannot fork" errors in bash?

Tags: bash, fork

For currently unknown reasons, one of our bash-scripts produces "Cannot fork" errors when running a simple line like:

```
myvar=`mycmd || echo "error"; exit 2`
```

Obviously the problem is that no new process can be created (forked) so that command fails.

However bash just ignores the error and continues in the script which caused unexpected problems.

As you can see, we already check for errors in the command itself, but the "Cannot fork" error appears before the command is even run.

Is there a way to catch that error and stop bash from execution?

Comment: Generally, this means you hit the applicable maximum number of concurrent processes.

Comment: Anyhow: `myvar=$(mycmd || { echo "error"; exit 2; } ) || exit` -- the `|| exit` causes the parent shell to exit if the command on the left side fails. Regular assignments where you don't use a builtin like `local` or `export` don't change exit status so it survives to be captured.

Comment: ...but I'd start by looking into _why_ you either have an unusually low limit (be it systemwide, or a ulimit, or a cgroup limit, etc) or an unusually high number of running processes.

Comment: Well, at the moment it seems to be one of those mysterious one-time-in-a-year v-server issues that cannot be reproduced. (Maybe the host system and not my v-server ran out of processes?) - Probably I will never know for sure...

Comment: But what I want to make sure is that if it happens again it does not cause more damage.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually several problems with this error check, that'll prevent it from properly handing *any* error, not just "Cannot fork" errors.

The first problem is that `||` has higher precedence than `;`, so `mycmd || echo "error"; exit 2` will run `echo "error"` only if `mycmd` fails, but it'll run `exit 2` *unconditionally*, whether or not `mycmd` succeeds or fails.

In order to fix this, you should group the error handling commands with `{ }`. Something like: `mycmd || { echo "error"; exit 2; }`. Note that a `;` or line break before `}` is required, or the `}` will be treated as an argument to `exit`.

(BTW, I sometimes see this shorthanded as `mycmd || echo "error" && exit 2`. Don't do this. If the `echo` fails for some weird reason, it won't run the `exit`.)

Also all of this, the `echo` and the `exit`, is run in the subshell created by the backticks (or would be, if that subshell had forked successfully). That means the error message will get saved in `myvar` rather than printed (error messages should generally be sent to standard error, e.g. `echo "error" >&2`); and more importantly it'll be the subshell that exits, not the shell that's running the script. The main script will note that the subshell exited with an error... and blithely keep running. (Well, unless you have `-e` set, but that's a [whole other ball of potential bugs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).)

The solution to that is to put the `||` stuff *outside* the backticks (or `$( ), since that's generally preferred over backticks). That way it happens in the main shell, that's what prints the error, that's what exits if there's an error, etc. This should also solve the "Cannot fork" problem, although I haven't tested it.

So, with all these corrections, it should look something like this:

```
myvar=$(mycmd) || {
    echo "error" >&2
    exit 2
}
```

Oh, and as Charles Duffy pointed out in a comment, if you use something like `local myvar=$(mycmd)` or `export myvar=$(mycmd)`, the `local`/`export`/whatever command will override the exit status from `mycmd`. If you need to do that, set the variable's properties separately from its value:

```
local myvar
myvar=$(mycmd) || {
...
```